# How to reform of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone solve my problem?
**Input :**

```
var input = [
    "a-b",
    "b-c",
    "c-d",
    "e-f"
];
```

**Output :**

```
var output = [
    "a-d",
    "e-f"
];
```

Comment: Have you tried on your own?

Comment: Did you try any code? What's the logic from one to the other?

Comment: and why output isn't `arr=["a-f"]`???

Comment: I guess you want to combine elements only, if the next element starts with the letter, the one before ends with, is that right?

Comment: yes  Markai. is it posibble?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @pallabmondal Can you create a JSFiddle, showing your approach, and we might be able to help you with improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular purpose, you can use this code:

```js
var input = [
    "a-b",
    "b-c",
    "c-d",
    "e-f",
    "j-k",
    "o-p",
    "p-q"
];
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "input: " + input;

function combineElements(array){
    var lastRange = array[0];
    var output = [];
    for(var index = 1; index < array.length; index++){
        if(lastRange[2] == array[index][0]){
            lastRange = lastRange.substring(0, 2) + array[index][2];
        }
        else{
            output.push(lastRange);
            lastRange = array[index];
        }
    }
    output.push(lastRange);
    return output;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "output: " + combineElements(input);
```

```html
<p id="input"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Or if you want it to be a little more dynamic (just checking for last and first character):

```js
var input = [
    "a-b",
    "b-c",
    "c-d",
    "e-f",
    "j-k",
    "o-p",
    "p-q"
];
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "input: " + input;

function combineElements(array){
    var lastRange = array[0];
    var output = [];
    for(var index = 1; index < array.length; index++){
        if(lastRange[lastRange.length-1] == array[index][0]){
            lastRange = lastRange.substring(0, lastRange.length-1) + array[index][array[index].length-1];
        }
        else{
            output.push(lastRange);
            lastRange = array[index];
        }
    }
    output.push(lastRange);
    return output;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "output: " + combineElements(input);
```

```html
<p id="input"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```